# Problem AD Password Filter DLL Implementation

Tags: c++, dll, active-directory, change-password

I have problems implementing a password filter DLL for my AD so I reduced it to the minimum as shown in the code below and when a user changes the password, it still doesn't work because I get this error : *"Unable to update the password. The value provided for the new password doest not meet the length, complexity, or history requirements of the domain"*.

Voici mon fichier **dllmain.cpp** :

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ntsecapi.h>

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}



__declspec(dllexport) BOOLEAN __stdcall InitializeChangeNotify(void)
{
   return TRUE;
}


__declspec(dllexport) BOOLEAN __stdcall PasswordFilter(
    PUNICODE_STRING AccountName,
    PUNICODE_STRING FullName,
    PUNICODE_STRING Password,
    BOOLEAN SetOperation
)
{
    return TRUE;
}


__declspec(dllexport) NTSTATUS __stdcall PasswordChangeNotify(
    PUNICODE_STRING UserName,
    ULONG RelativeId,
    PUNICODE_STRING NewPassword
)
{
    return 0;
}
```

I compile my DLL with *Visual Studio 2022* then I send it to my AD in `C:\Windows\System32`. Then I add in the subkey **Notification Packages** of `SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Lsa` in Regedit the name of my DLL. Then finally I reboot the AD.

I think I have minimized the code and still returns "True" but it still doesn't work...

Comment: It's a Security Policy Setting see [Password must meet complexity requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/password-must-meet-complexity-requirements)

Comment: Unfortunately it's not that, I already checked :/